# Where does The Doctor get a (new) TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Remember when The Doctor got a brand new TARDIS? Where does he get them from?

Aren't almost all the Time Lords dead? Who else (except maybe the Daleks or the tiny people inside robots) would build a TARDIS?

Comment: No, I don't remember when this happened. When did it happen?

Comment: @Keen Spoilers!

Comment: Do you mean it looked suddenly different inside and out? Yeah, she likes to redecorate herself every now and then (meaning it isn't new at all, just the *"Old Girl" in a new dress*, if you will). If you didn't mean that, @randal'thor quoting River Song *strongly* applies.

Comment: @BMWurm OP accepted my answer, so *probably* meant the (spoilery and awesome) events at the end of series 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm assuming that your question refers to the events at the end of series 9. If not, SPOILERS!**

Gallifrey wasn't destroyed: in the 50th anniversary special *The Day of the Doctor*, we discovered that in fact it was locked out of time and space but remained intact. So no, it's not the case that almost all the Time Lords are dead.

The Time Lords and Gallifrey have since returned to this universe, although they placed themselves near the very end of it. That was how the Doctor could return there in the series 9 finale *Hell Bent*. And it was on Gallifrey that the TARDISes were stored, all the way through. When the Doctor returned there, he was able to steal a TARDIS in just the same way as before - from the people who made them, in the place where they came from.